# Format mongodb query to create pandas DataFrame using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pandas, dictionary, pymongo

I'm trying to plug my query object in the pymongo connector:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


def _connect_mongo(host, port, username, password, db):

    if username and password:
        mongo_uri = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (username, password, host, port, db)
        conn = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    else:
        conn = MongoClient(host, port)


    return conn[db]


def read_mongo(db, collection, query={}, host='localhost', port=27017, username=None, password=None, no_id=True):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, username=username,  password=password, db=db)

    # Make a query to the specific DB and Collection
    cursor = db[collection].find(query)
    # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

    # Delete the _id
    # if no_id:
    #    del df['_id']

    return df
```

My query is defined as:

```
query_1 = "{
                    "status" : {"$ne" : "deprecated"}, 
                    "geoLocationData.date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2016-08-03") }
                 },
                    { "geoLocationData.date": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.iso": 1,
                      "httpRequestData.ipAddress": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.city": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.latitude": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.longitude": 1  }"
```

to plug it into - getting a pandas dataframe:

```
df = read_mongo(db, collection, query_1, host, port, username, password)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type    that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

If I just omit the subdocuments, the query works just fine and I'm able to convert it into a dataframe.

I guess it's about converting my query into a dictionary (with sub-documents).
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you giving the query as a string as implied by `query_1 = "db.finger...})"`?

Comment: Sorry I edited. I'm defining the query omitting the find statement @SteveRossiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `query_1` variable is a string which seems to contain two dictionaries. The [`find`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method takes a dictionary as the filter argument first and then a projection as the second argument. You are only passing one argument.

This should work:

```
def read_mongo(db, collection, filter={}, projection={}, host='localhost', port=27017, username=None, password=None, no_id=True):
    """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

    # Connect to MongoDB
    db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, username=username,  password=password, db=db)

    # Make a query to the specific DB and Collection
    cursor = db[collection].find(filter, projection)
    # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
    df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

    # Delete the _id
    # if no_id:
    #    del df['_id']

    return df 

query_filter = {
                    "status" : {"$ne" : "deprecated"}, 
                    "geoLocationData.date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2016-08-03") }
                 }
query_project = { "geoLocationData.date": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.iso": 1,
                      "httpRequestData.ipAddress": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.city": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.latitude": 1,
                      "geoLocationData.longitude": 1  }

df = read_mongo(db, collection, query_filter, query_project,  host, port, username, password)
```

However, I don't think that this method can co quite what you want it to do. This is because the projection in a `find` operation can only include or exclude fields it doesn't map them in the way you want. You could iterate over your cursor to manipulate the data before passing into the `DataFrame` constructor (beware not to create huge python lists). The better way is not to use `find` at all but to use [`aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate):

```
cursor = db[collection].aggregate([filter, projection])
```

Now you can make your filter a `match` pipeline stage and the projection a `project` stage.

```
query_project = { "geoDate":"$geoLocationData.date",
                  "geoLoc":"$geoLocationData.iso",
                   "ipAddress": "$httpRequestData.ipAddress",
                     "city": "$geoLocationData.city",
                      "lat": "$geoLocationData.latitude",
                      "long":"$geoLocationData.longitude"}

df = read_mongo(db, collection, {"$match" : query_filter}, {"$project" : query_project},  host, port, username, password)
```

Comment: It works and loads the data. Now I have each column representing an embedded document (ie. geoLocationData and httpRequestsData) are in this format: 
   `{u'city': u'Vantaa',
   u'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 29, 10, 59, 23, 361000),
   u'iso': u'FI',
   u'latitude': u'60.3131',
   u'longitude': u'24.9507'}`.

How do I parse it unfolding them in different columns? @SteveRossiter

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what i think you're trying to do. You should try to understand the aggregation framework as it's most efficient and powerful way to query mongodb.

Comment: When I run the code it gives:
`df = read_mongo(db, collection, {$match : query_filter}, {$project : query_project},  host, port, username, password)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
`
if I try to put the match in quotes as:

`"{$match : query_filter}", "{$project : query_project}"`

I get:


`TypeError: aggregate() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

@SteveRossiter

Comment: Sorry in python "$match" and "$project" need to be in quotes (they don't in the mongodb shell)

Comment: still the same problem as `aggregate() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)` even with `df = read_mongo(db, collection, {"$match" : query_filter}, {'$project' : query_project},  host, port, username, password)`. Maybe match and project should be somehow aggregated? @SteveRossiter

Comment: I can't follow exactly what you are executing.  But I suspect you are passing elements to `aggregate` as separate arguments and not a list.  The argument to `aggregate` needs to be a list of pipeline stages.  
`db.aggregate([{'$match': query_filter}, {'$project': query_project}])`